# Rhodes application - How to navigate screen on table row touch?

Tags: html, rhomobile, rhodes, tablerow

I want to perform navigate to other screen when I touch a table row. To do so I did the following :

```
<table>
<tr><a href="<%= url_for :controller => :Products %>"></a>
<td width="80"><img src="http://images.bizrate.com/resize?sq=60&uid=2605377575" width="80px"></img></td>
<td>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="260"><label for="label1">GPS Navigation System-$68.00</label></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
<td width="260"><label for="label2">TomTom 3.5 One 125</label></td>  
        </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

But nothing happened. I also tried to apply `<a href="<%= url_for :controller => :Products %>"></a>` in **td**. Still no success. Finally I tried with unordered lists. Still nothing happened.
How can we navigate to other screen on table row touch?

Comment: I have no idea of javascript. An example would be really helpful. (Example of navigating on row touch using javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an action in your anchor tag, not just a controller.  You can try something like the following:

```
<table>
   <tr onclick="rowClick();">
     <td width="80"><img src="http://images.bizrate.com/resize?sq=60&uid=2605377575" width="80px"></img></td>
     <td>
       <table>
         <tr>
           <td width="260"><label for="label1">GPS Navigation System-$68.00</label></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td width="260"><label for="label2">TomTom 3.5 One 125</label></td>  
         </tr>
       </table>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function rowClick() {
    window.location = "<%= url_for :controller => :Products, :action => :show, :params => { :item_id => 1234 } %>";
  }
</script>
```